# React Native - Adding a new view seems to have a default fade in animation

Tags: animation, react-native

Every time I render a new view it seems to have a default fade in animation where the opacity goes from 0 - 1 over about 200 milliseconds. Is there any way to turn this off so the view appears immediately?

Sample code that would trigger the default animation;

```
{(() => {
   if (itemIsOpen) {
      return (
         <CardOverlay />
      )
   }
})()}
```

CardOverlay component fades in when I want it to immediately appear.

Comment: Other [user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7229259/kiwi-gee) are [interested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40884752/5292302) to know if you solved this, consider to pass an answer if you did.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same thing for a while now, it's been driving me around the bend but I've *finally* found the cause of it. Not sure if it's the same thing that caused your problem (and not sure if it's still relevant for you) but I thought I'd share it incase someone runs into the same problem.

My issue was caused by Animated.spring() -- I was using it on a sub-component (a little button that makes an image appear on the page) but it seems that as soon as you add spring *anywhere* in your visual tree it affects everything. Even if you put it in componentDidMount on the inner component it still affects the page-load animation for me.

Time to learn a bit more about how the react Animated library works methinks!